# Left Outer Join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, outer-join

```
List<ServicePacksDTO> allServicePacks = new List<ServicePacksDTO>();
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            allServicePacks=(
                    from sp in db.ServicePacks
                    join st in db.States.DefaultIfEmpty() on sp.State_id equals st.State_Id
                    join type in db.ServiceTypes on sp.ServiceType_Id equals type.ServiceType_Id
                    where
                     (type.ServiceType_desc.ToLower() == "accepted") 
                    orderby sp.AustState_id
                    select sp.ToServicePacksDTO(db)).ToList();
        }
```

The current code works fine, until I attempt to do an outer join on state. Is there away to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, you need to provide a bit more detail that "works fine, until i attempt to do xx".

What doesn't work? Is there an error? Unexpected results?

Forgetting about the DTO projection and `db.ServiceTypes` join, to do a LOJ between `db.ServicePacks` and `db.States`, do this:

```
var x = (from sp in db.ServicePacks
join st in db.States on sp.State_id equals st.State_id into spst
from x in spst.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { /* fields */ }
).ToList();
```

Try that first, make sure that works (it should), and then add on your other join and projection.